# Button not displaying in view

Tags: react-native, flexbox

Hw can align my `Button` to the bottom of my `RadioGroup`?

```
 <View
        style={{
          height: 200,
          padding: 12
        }}
      >
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, color: "#fff", textAlign: "right" }}>
          {this.props.current + 1} out of 10
        </Text>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 32, fontWeight: "bold", color: "#fff" }}>
          {this.props.question.question}
        </Text>
        <RadioGroup
          onSelect={(index, answer) => onSelect(answer)}
          selectedIndex={null}
        >
          {this.renderOptions(question)}
        </RadioGroup>
        <TouchableHighlight
          style={{
            height: 40,
            width: 160,
            borderRadius: 10,
            backgroundColor: "yellow",
            marginLeft: 50,
            marginRight: 50,
            marginTop: 20
          }}
        >
          <Button
            title="Submit Answer"
            color="#fff"
            onPress={() => {
              this.props.onSelect(this.state.answer);
            }}
          />
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a `<View style={{flexDireaction: "row"}}><View>content radio group</View><View>content button</View> </View>` Try wrap it in a view and add styling:
`position: 'absolute', right: 0, bottom: 0` or
`flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column-reverse'`

Answer (score 0):

The button is not displaying because you have a fixed `height` in `<View>` parent and the button is in a position bigger than 200 height. Try to increase the `height` of the parent, or remove it and add `flex: 1`.